# Disable windows 8 built in indicators

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to disable Windows 8's built in volume indicator and brightness indicator that appear whenever you adjust the volume/brightness level by keyboard?

Comment: I assume this is a laptop.  I would just not install the driver for this functionality.  This is handled by the driver.

Comment: this is no driver, it comes with windows 8 by default